# "Unable to retrieve Server list" error when viewing network shares (internet in browser works)

Tags: 10.10, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share between Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16104/share-between-ubuntu-machines)

I'm getting this error, although since installing Ubuntu 10.10 the network DID work once, but now I get this error all the time.

Where do I go to resolve ?  Network config is far from obvious from the Gui !

Answer (score 2):

You may not be on the same WORKGROUP as your other shares - so a list is unable to be generated.

Try connecting directly to the share via it's IP address and protocol to ensure you're still able to see and reach any share.

Comment: as an example of how to do this, try running in terminal this command: nautilus smb://se.rv.er.ip


if this works and you see the share, i'd just bookmark it.