# Share between Ubuntu machines

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I'm sure it might be a very easy way to do this, but I haven't found how...
I have two machines with Ubuntu 10.10 on the same network (just workgroup, no domain involved). On one of them I have shared a folder through Nautilus **Folder Sharing**. When opening the Network *place* on the second machine, I cannot see the first one listed, just *Windows Network* and when going into this folder I can see the *Workgroup* though when trying to go into it I get an *Unable to mount. Failed to retrieve share list from server* error.

Is it required to do something else when sharing the folder through Nautilus?

Comment: using smb://<machine name>/<share folder> from Run Application dialog, I can reach the shared location with Nautilus

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to retrieve Server list" error when viewing network shares (internet in browser works)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6441/unable-to-retrieve-server-list-error-when-viewing-network-shares-internet-in-b)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Method 1:**
 You can use SAMBA for file sharing(but samba is mostly used to share files between linux and windows machines)

- In terminal type the following `gksudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`
- Add the line **usershare owner only = False**  to the [global] section.
- Go to Places>>Computer.
- Right click the folder you want to share and choose **Sharing Options**.
  [image]
- Check the box that says **Share this folder**.
- Write your share name and check the box that says **Allow other people to write in this folder**.
- Now you should be able to see and access the shared folder from your network.

**Method 2:**
You can use Openssh run the following to install it,

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Now goto **Places** menu and choose **Connect to Server**

(In oneiric (11.10), click desktop and use the menu at the top: **File** --> **Connect to Server**)

[image]

- In the **Service type:** Select **SSH**
- In **Server:** give the **IP address** of the PC where the info is on.
- In **Port:** give **22**.
- Now in **Folder:** Pick the folder you wish to share.
- In **User Name:** give the username of the pc you are connected to.
- Click Connect after that you will get a windows where you have to enter a password of the PC you are trying to connect to.
- Now you have read/write permissions.

Comment: Graphical programs should not be run with sudo. The correct way is to use kdesudo in KDE for running GUI programs as root, or gksu/gksudo in GNOME.

Running graphical programs as root has the potential to cause serious issues, that is why the wrappers are provided. Read this Arch mailing list thread for a serious issue that you could encounter trying to trick sudo into launching a GUI
http://www.mail-archive.com/arch@archlinux.org/msg04963.html

Comment: I can't find *Connect To Server* in Ubuntu 11.04. Where is it

Comment: I am not sure where it is in ubuntu 11.04. I think you should rise a question :)

Comment: SSH are a much better solution than the old and clunky Samba. 
In 11.04 and further the "Connect to server..." menu have moved to Nautilus File-menu.

Comment: Method 1 in the top answer (concerning SAMBA configuration) fails for machines on Ubuntu 16.04. One can only access the network directory using the owner's credentials notwithstanding group create/delete permissions on the share, and individual user write access permissions on SAMBA.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to share files b/w two Linux systems. The most easy and common way is SSH.

Method 1: SSH

Install ssh on both systems.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Then Go to 'Places' menu and select 'Connect to server'.

[image]

Method 2: use giver

Giver allows you to drag and drop files to users on your network. It will also automatically detect other Giver users on your network.

When you drag a file, or multiple files, to a user represented by an avatar on the Giver window, the files are automatically transferred. The recipient of the files is warned that a user wishes to send files. The user can accept or decline them.

To install giver in ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install giver

Answer (score 5):

Once you set up an SSH server on one machine, you can simply connect to the other one via Nautilus by typing sftp://192.168.1.3 (or whatever the actual IP number of the other machine is) in the location bar (invoked with CTRL-L).

Answer (score 1):

if no Windows machines involved - only Linux, you can use NFS (more native for linux)

[nfs shares](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/03/01/share-ubuntu-folders-with-nfs/)

long story short:

on server: in /etc/exports you put the folders need to be exported

on the clients: mount the share  (auto in /etc/fstab or manual- CLI or nautilus)

Answer (score 1):

I have a big computer which we will call Upstairs and a little computer which we will call Downstairs. They are on the same network, connected by the same router. Upstairs is running Kubuntu (12.04) whereas Downstairs is running bogstandard Ubuntu (13.04, with KDE desktop). I prefer to work on Downstairs but often need to access my files on Upstairs, which my partner may be using at the time.

I shared some Upstairs directories using Samba first of all and this was a nightmare. First of all it didn't work recursively (I had to mark every directory and sub-directory) I wanted to share). Secondly, although Downstairs could see Upstairs on the network,  when I clicked into the shared directories I kept being prompted for a password, and although I was entering it correctly the password was not recognized so I couldn't get in. I am tempted to forget Samba altogether but first let's see how it gets on with making my Upstairs music files available to my excellent internet radio.

Next I tried [nfs as suggested by the user *jet*](https://askubuntu.com/a/19432/25798). Following the instructions suggested by the link, this worked perfectly the first time. Unfortunately when I tried again the following day after both computers had been rebooted, I kept getting `mount.nfs: Access Denied...` messages. This problem is well documented in the forums but the multifarious proposed solutions are beyond my level of technical ability.

---

This was my solution. Install ssh on the host (server) computer (or both), as suggested by aneeshep:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Now on the client computer (or both) install a package called `sshfs`:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Using your preferred file manager on Downstairs, check that Upstairs is on the network. If so, make a directory on Downstairs where you will mount the Upstairs file system. Let's call it `/home/me_downstairs/UpstairsFiles/`

Now, at the command line, type something like, followed by Return:

```
sshfs yourloginname@Upstairs.local:/home/me_upstairs /home/me_downstairs/UpstairsFiles/
```

(This is all on one line.)

Of course, replace 'Upstairs' by the name of your computer as shown on the network, but the .local suffix is important.

You will be prompted to enter your Upstairs password.

Now, in the directory `/home/me_downstairs/UpstairsFiles/` on Downstairs I can see all my Upstairs files and use them as normal.

---

This website below suggests some extra steps may be necessary but they weren't for me:

http://itecsoftware.com/mount-remote-folder-via-ssh-using-sshfs

Please let me know if this did or did not work for you.