# How to share files Between RHEL and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, file-sharing

I have installed RHEL 5.5 on VIrtual Box and Host system is Ubuntu 12.04. I can access the files of Ubuntu by using the sharing services of Virtual Box.

[image: Virtual Box]

**But how can i access the files of RHEL which is installed on Virtual Box??????**

Answer (score 0):

*Virtual Box Shared Folders* provide access to host directories from a guest OS. This does not work the other way, i.e. accessing guest directories from the host.

To do so you may want to access file across a virtual network using **SSH** or **Samba**. See this questions for more (it should be the same for RHEL):

- [Share between Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16104/share-between-ubuntu-machines)