# What's the most efficient way to connect two Ubuntu 12.04LTS machines hard-drives

Tags: file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share between Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16104/share-between-ubuntu-machines)

I have a MacPro desktop and a Dell laptop. I want to connect them such that file sharing is as fast as possible. Possibly I'd like to see the hard-drives of each machine mounted making the copying process seamless:

Copying from MacPro to Dell:

```
cp /mnt/macpro/home/foo /home/path-to-somewhere
```

Copying from Dell to MacPro:

```
cp /mnt/dell/home/foo /home/path-to-somewhere
```

Any suggestion?

In practice I have a lot of data (therabytes) and I want to exploit all the cpu-cores I have to process them.

Comment: I really don't think this is a duplicate. I am asking what's the MOST efficient way. For example which is the fastest protocol to use among nfs,samba,ftp,sftp.

Answer (score 1):

over the network :

You can use file sharing software like [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net/downloads)

or else you can use default public sharing:

http://www.howtogeek.com/116309/use-ubuntus-public-folder-to-easily-share-files-between-computers/

or else Ultracopier is software you can use to copy locally from drive to drive

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, this question provides the answer: [Share between Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16104)

Use method 2 described there. To find out the IP adress of one machine (so it can be entered on the other), open a terminal and run this command:

```
ifconfig
```

Also, an abundance of CPU cores won't do you any good. The bottleneck here is the network.