# File Sharing between Ubuntu machines fails: permission denied

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I am trying to to use File Sharing between two Ubuntu machines on a local network. box2 is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 and box3 is running Ubuntu 16.04, both OS are up to date.

Personal File Sharing Preferences for the folder “Public” on box3 are set to share public files on network and “Never” require a password.

[image: Screenshot: Personal File Sharing Preferences]

When accessing the public folder from box2 a password *is* required for share public on box3.

[image: Screenshot: Password required for share public on box3]

Connection attempt as Anonymous without a password fail.

> **Unable to access location**
>   Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied

Fun fact: the same thing happen when trying to access smb://box3/Public from box3.

I have also tried the settings “Require password: When writing files” and “Require password: Always”, this will cause

> **Oops! Something went wrong.**
>   Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied

**UPDATE**

Reading [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/16126/563581) to a similiar (but not quite the same) problem, I decided to give Openssh a try, and installed openssh-server openssh-client. Voilà, I can now access the folder Public on box3. Just not via Samba. Permission is still denied.

Comment: I have the same problem - I'd be interested in finding out how to solve it, too.

Comment: Jay! I am not alone! \\(^.^)/

Comment: If you're sharing between two Linux systems, why not [use NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) instead? Is there any particular reason you are using SMB? (And you're welcome, I saw the comment, that's why I deleted it :) )

Comment: I did not know about NFS, so thanks for the lead! I am actually in a mixed (Linux/Windows ) local network, so Samba probably still is my best option. Besides Samba was my first choice because I took it for granted that the File Sharing function in Nautilus/Files should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Viewed 1k times over 4 years and not *one* answer. Apparently File Sharing between Ubuntu machines this is a tough nut.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. The problem disappeared only when I removed whole [public] section from smb.config. I still don't know the cause, since the path in [public] was valid and the folder was accessible with proper permissions.