# Share between Ubuntu 18.10 machines without Samba

Tags: networking, samba

I have bought a new laptop and want to transfer files from the old machine to the new one. Both machines are running Ubuntu 18.10.

I have installed openssh-server on the old machine but when I right click on file and select "Share in local network" a popup tells me to install Samba. I thought that Samba was for sharing files with a Windows machine. Is there not a way to share between two Ubuntu (18.10) machines without using Samba?

The "duplicate" linked to is very old and deals with Ubuntu 10.10. Things have changed a bit in eight years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share between Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16104/share-between-ubuntu-machines)

Comment: The "duplicate" is very old and deals with Ubuntu 10.10. Things have changed a bit in eight years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share files/folders between two different Ubuntu computers and are on different network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871240/how-to-share-files-folders-between-two-different-ubuntu-computers-and-are-on-dif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Samba works on Ubuntu as well as Windows, so it is not only for Windows machines.

It is also easy to get similar functionality with ssh. One way is to type `sftp://serverhostname` in the file browser's address bar (ctrl+l). That should prompt for username and password, and then open a file browser window into the server filesystem. Then you can copy/paste files.

PS: You may need to login once from a terminal windows so that the known host file is updated.