# Downloading Files from Digital Ocean Droplet using Linux Terminal- SSH access

Tags: ssh, downloads

I have a digital ocean droplet. I am able to connect to it using SSH and see the file list in the terminal. There is a folder in the droplet which I would like to download to my PC. How can I do that using a Ubuntu Linux terminal? Or should I use some FTP software to do that in Linux?

Comment: I don't know your specifics, but you're using secure-shell (`ssh`) to shell into the box, I'd use secure-copy (`scp`) to copy files using the same mechanism.

Comment: Thank You. I searched for scp and it worked. Sorry if it was a dumb question, I am very new to linux

Comment: Not a problem, if you `man ssh` to view the reference manual page for `ssh`, you'll note a *SEE ALSO* section which includes other commands that may be useful, where `scp` is first, `sftp` second etc...  There are loads of tools as get the hang of it  (and when you forget commands, `apropos` or use autocomplete..

Comment: Actually, ssh provides sftp, and you can use a file browser to connect and copy files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126120/share-between-ubuntu-18-10-machines-without-samba/1126122#1126122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `open-sshserver` comes with enabled SFTP feature, so you can use it as it is described here: [Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/987769/566421).

For a single file or directory (also with recursion) either `scp` or `rsync` are appropriate. For better performance I would use `rsync` in a way as this:

```
rsync -av user@host:/remote/path/to/<file or directory> /local/path/<to be placed>
```

---

In the [topic](https://askubuntu.com/q/987769/566421) mentioned above, I'm describing also how to setup and use the `~/.ssh/config` file. Because you are *new to linux*, if you are not familiar with that, IMO, this part will be useful for you.